# In an array, what does &arr[2] return?

Tags: c, arrays

If we have an array[5], we know that arr == &arr[0]
but what is &arr[2] = ?

Also, what does &arr return to us?

Comment: Language tag missing. Is this C? C++? PHP? ...

Comment: I'm curious how it differs in C and C++ both..

Comment: `&arr` doesn't "return" anything. It is not a function.

Comment: @Siddhartha: It's the same in both.

Comment: @Siddhartha: They are the same thing in both C and C++.

Comment: Ok so Suppose we had a ptr a= *b (where b is an integer)
If we say, &a, it's going to give us the memory location of 'a' right?
similarly, since 'arr' is a pointer (to the first element), shouldn't &arr give us some address too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a simple example first:

```
int a;
a = 5;
```

In a sense the integer **a** has two values assoicated with it. The one you most 
likely think about first is the rvalue, which in this case is the number 5. 
There is also what is called an lvalue (pronounced "el value") which is the 
memory address the integer **a** is located at.

This is an important concept to grasp. At the end of the day everything is all 
about memory. We store code and variables in memory. The CPU executes 
instructions which are located in memory and it performs actions on data which 
is also in memory. It's all just memory. Nothing very complicated; if someone 
tries to scare you with pointers don't listen, it's all just memory :)

Alrighty so, in the case of an array we are dealing with a contiguious block of
memory that is used for storing data of the same type:

```
int array[] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};
```

As you have already noted the name of the array refers to the memory location of
the first element in the array (e.g. array == &array[0]). So in my example array
above &array[2] would refer to the memory location (or lvalue) that contains the
third element in the array.

To answer your other question &array is just another memory address, see if 
this code snippet helps clear up what it points to :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int array[] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};

int main(void) {
    printf("&array[2] is: %p\n", &array[2]);
    printf("&array[0] is: %p\n", &array[0]);
    printf("&array is: %14p\n", &array);
    exit(0);
}

% gcc test.c
% ./a.out
&array[2] is: 0x100001088
&array[0] is: 0x100001080
&array is:    0x100001080
```

Comment: Ahhhh I always wondered what lvalue was...I always get an 'invalid lvalue assignment' error when I used '=' instead of '==' ..it makes sense now.           
I was aware that everything happens in memory..
Hmmm I wasn't sure if &array would indeed be a valid memory address, but I put this into codepad.org and you're right. I guess &array == &array[0]
Also, what is I'm guessing %p gives the lvalue? if so, what does %14p do?
Thx a ton :D

Comment: %p is the format specifier to use when printing a memory address with the printf function. The number 14 tells printf to pad the output until it is at least 14 characters wide; take it out and see the difference in the output. I am guessing that you are reading a book on the C programming language and in a few chapters you will encounter information on the relationship between pointers and arrays. Once you read that the rest of the comments from the other posters may make more sense. Also, I highly recommend you read this document from Ted Jensen it will clear a lot up: http://mkurl.us/2YW

Answer (score 3):

In c, the only difference between `[]` operator and the `+` operator is that the `[]` operator also dereferences the pointer. This means that `arr[2] == *(arr + 2)`, and `&arr[2] == &(*(arr + 2)) == arr + 2`.

On a side note, this also means the fun interaction wherein you reference array indexes like `index[array]`: that is, `arr[2] == 2[arr]`.

The more you know....

Answer (score 2):

> If we have an array[5], we know that arr = &arr[0] but what is &arr[2] = ?

In a C based language, `&arr[0]` is a pointer to the first element in the array while `&arr[2]` is a pointer to the third element in the array. Arrays decay into pointers to the first element, so in certain context `array` and `&arr[0]` are actually the same thing: a pointer to the first element.

Comment: I thought just 'arr' did that?

Comment: @Siddhartha: `arr` decays to a pointer to the first element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
&arr[0] == arr + 0
&arr[1] == arr + 1
&arr[2] == arr + 2
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In both C and C++, if `T` is a fundamental type, and you have an array `T array[N]`, then `array[i]` is `*(array+i)`, using the fact that the expression `array` decays to a pointer type in an expression.