# Program stops after loop in function

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops

My prog doesn't reach outArray function. it stops after loop of fillArray function. Why this happens. It looks strangely, cause it's simple void function and shouldn't return anything. This should continue run commands in main. And that stops as usual program without any problems and bugs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

int enterNofArray();
void fillArray(int n, float arr[N]);
void outArray(int n, float arr[N]);

int main()
{
    float arr[N], sum = 0.0, average;
    int n;

    //input
    n = enterNofArray();

    //compute
    fillArray(n, &arr[N]);

    //output
    outArray(n, &arr[N]);

    return 0;
}


int enterNofArray()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter amount of array...\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (n < 1 || n > N)
    {
        printf("Incorrect!!\n");
        printf("Enter in range 1 - 100...\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    return n;
}

void fillArray(int n, float arr[N])
{
    int num;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number for array[%d times left]...\n", n - i);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        arr[i] = num;
    }
}

void outArray(int n, float arr[N])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%f ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return values of your `scanf` calls for errors.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. it returns 1. standard return value

Comment: It's not "standard", it means something and you might want to look what in it's documentation. But yeah, if every call is returning 1 it's not an error. Anyway, I don't quite understand, what do you mean by "stops" ?

Comment: Eugene Sh. by stops i mean end of execution prog, but prog should execute next instruction (outArray func.)

Comment: Why do you think it is not executing? Not seeing any output? Try `fflush(stdout)` in the end.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I tried that and as result is output of all arr numbers. But I don't understand why this happens. I for interest compile that prog in online compiler and that show me segmentation fault. I saw common causes of this problem (Forgetting to use "&" on the arguments to scanf, Accessing beyond the bounds of an array, Failure to initialize a pointer before accessing it, Incorrect use of the "&" (address of) and "*" (dereferencing) operators) but but none of them fit my case.

Comment: `fillArray(n, &arr[N])`  --> `fillArray(n, arr)`, and similarly for the call to `outArray()`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, I use gcc for compile my programs, and it doesn’t show me any error(segfault) as online compiler

Comment: Ahh.. @JohnBollinger nailed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&arr[N]` refers to the memory location (or lvalue) that contains the N-th (out of index!!!) element in the array.

That code invokes *Undefined Behavior* (UB).

So, you weren't actually passing the whole array to your functions, you were just attempting to pass the N-th element of that array... Read more about that expression [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761663/in-an-array-what-does-arr2-return).

Change this:

```
fillArray(n, &arr[N]);
outArray(n, &arr[N]);
```

to this:

```
fillArray(n, arr);
outArray(n, arr);
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MjUuMnNol9RKwHdx)</kbd>

The problem was that with your code `n` was corrupted, containing garbage value after the call to `fillArray` function. As a result, when `outArray` function was called, `n` had a garbage value, which resulted in an uncontrolled for-loop that ended in looping far further than the limits of your array, eventually accessing memory that you didn't own, thus causing a Segmentation Fault.

---

Not the cause of your problem, but I suggest you do `scanf("%f", &num);` in your `fillArray` function (after declaring `num` as a `float` of course), since you want to populate an array of floats.

Comment: Thanks, that works properly. How I understand when array using in function as argument - you should pass to func just point to the first element. Name of array without index points to the first elem. Am I right?

Comment: You are welcome! From the linked answer @helsereet "the name of the array refers to the memory location of the first element in the array (i.e. `arr == &arr[0])`. "

Answer (score 0):

Because you're send double pointer when you do this:

fillArray(n, &arr[N]);
outArray(n, &arr[N]);

Looks like:

fillArray(n, **arr);
outArray(n, **arr);

This happends so much when you work with Structures.